# Why i only get 1 row of ans?

Tags: php, mysql

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if (isset($row["name"]) && ($row["name"] != "")){
            $contentStr = $row["name"];
        }
        break;
    }
    mysql_close($con);`

This works but not the way i want. 
I want to show all the data that i get from.
Example in got 4 data now on database and using \n for the next line to show another data. How to write the format ?

Comment: On top of @Saty's comment, remove the `break;`, though I believe you want string concatenation rather than arrays.

Comment: Why you use `break;` ??

Comment: I got 4 data in database. But when i try the code i only get 1 row of data. I tried remove break; but its still show one row ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove the break. It is serving no purpose.

Now, I believe what you want to do is obtain all the row["name"] values into one String, namely $contentStr, separated by a newline.

If this is the case, use the following:

```
$contentStr .= $row["name"] . "\n"
```

Also, make sure to create an empty $contentStr before the loop.

Comment: Yeah, follow your way, its working. Thank you so much. I have tried to settle this for few days already. Between that, if no result after search whr should i put this $contentStr = "There is no the name your seach" ?

Comment: simply add a line after the loop to check if contentStr is empty.
if($contentStr == '') $contentStr = "There is no the name your seach";